# System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#

When I run this code, I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in @override.exe
>   Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'animals.Animal' to type 'animals.dog'.

```
class Animal
{
    public string name = "sdsfsdf";
    public virtual void bark() {
        Console.WriteLine("woohhoo");
    }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public int id = 11;         
    public  override void bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("woof");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal a = new Animal();    
        //bark;
        a.bark();

        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.bark();

        // take out the virtual and override keyword infront of the method bark and see the difference*/

        Animal z = new Dog();
        z.bark();

        Console.WriteLine(z.name);

        Dog f = (Dog) new Animal();
        f.bark();

        Console.ReadKey();               
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that an `Animal` is a `Dog`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this cast because an `Animal` is not a `Dog`.

However, a `Dog` is an `Animal` so you can do:

```
Animal a = (Animal) new Dog();
```